# Mstest - does not load the test dll if UNC path is referenced in the testcontainer

Tags: mstest

I am trying to run a automated test run from the MS Test Manager.  It was not running and the log showed "Error adding test case [123] to test run: Could not load file or assembly 'file://\localhost\TFS\OGUI\OGUI_20111228.8\catsprojects.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."

When I tested the dll by using the MsTest (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsmantest/thread/011a89b7-8c90-436b-bc08-f5e90165c908) seems the dll is loaded when it is locally referenced.  It runs the test successfuly.

> mstest /testcontainer:D:\TFS\OGUI\OGUI_20111228.8\CATSProjects.dll"

But with UNC Path, it fails to load.

> mstest /testcontainer:"\200411dc0310\TFS\OGUI\OGUI_20111228.8\CATSProjects.dll"
>   Could not load file or assembly 'file://\200411dc0310\TFS\OGUI\OGUI_20111228.8\CATSProjects.dll' or one of its dependencies. Operation is not supported. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131515)

Fixing this should allow me to run the automated test run from the MTM.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Mush

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your UNC path is wrong? UNC paths start with `\\`, and it seems you only have a single `\`